# ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at test.main(test.java:8)

Tags: java

```
//i m doing this program for checking switch condition but there is an error
```

so can you please help to solve this
    public class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    **char grade = args[0].charAt(0);**//here is the error

try {
    switch (grade){
            case A:{
        System.out.println("CASE A");
        break;
    }
    case 'B':{
        System.out.println("CASE B");
    }
    case 'C':{
        System.out.println("CASE C");
    }
    case 'D':{
        System.out.println("CASE D");
    }
    default:
        System.out.println("last");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
System.out.println("what is this");

    }       
    }
```

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error occuring how should i resolve it

Comment: You must start your program with parameters.

Comment: And please don't make modifications to the non-comment portion of your code. It took me a second to realize you hadn't confused Java with C.

Comment: thanks i have made the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
      if(args.length>0){
        **char grade = args[0].charAt(0);**//here is the error
      }else{
          char grade='F';
      }

try {
    switch (grade){
            case 1:{
        System.out.println("CASE A");
        break;
    }
    case 'B':{
        System.out.println("CASE B");
    }
    case 'C':{
        System.out.println("CASE C");
    }
    case 'D':{
        System.out.println("CASE D");
    }
    default:
        System.out.println("last");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
System.out.println("what is this");

    }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are executing it without passing the necessary arguments.  Have you made sure that you are passing them?

Answer (score 0):

[CommandLineArgument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)

you are doing the command line argument.give the argument when you run the code  otherwise you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

check the length of the `args[]` length and then use the value

```
if(args.length>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

is a main thread. **args** is an argument which stores the command line parameters that we passed along the program. Please execute program by passing arguments like:

```
java ProgramName ThisIsArgument1 ThisIsArgument2 ManyMoreOptionalArguments
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke your java program through the command line with something like:

`java SwitchTest 1`

This guy here 'String[] args' (this array of Strings is part of the signature of your main method) will take all the arguments, i.e., elements that are added after the command to execute your program (`java SwitchTest`), which, in this example, is `1`.

If you execute your program like this, with the code you have there:

`java SwitchTest 1`

Your output should be:

`CASE A`

If you execute without any arguments (i.e., nothing after `java SwitchTest`), you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing it a runtime argument? Try this:

```
Command Line> java test A
```

Or try this:

```
char grade = '[Char in here]';
```

Which would be like this:

```
char grade = 'A';
```